# Thread interruption does not stop program immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have created sort of a Sound class using sun.audio. (I know it is deprecated. Please don't mention it.)

For some reason, the thread doesn't quite stop when it is supposed to no matter what I have tried.

Here is my Sound class:

```
package bob.classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;

/*
 * Custom class for playing audio (audio file must be in src)
 */
public class Sound {
    private ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null; //Puts music data into loop
    private InputStream in = null; //Takes in music file as input
    private AudioStream audioStreamMusic = null; //Takes in InputStream of music file as input
    private AudioData audioData = null; //Changes AudioStream to data
    private boolean loopable; //Whether the music input is meant to be looped or not
    private String music; //The name of the music file
    private double length; //The duration of the audio snippet in seconds

    /*
     * Takes in music file name and whether or not the file is loopable
     */
    public Sound(String music, boolean loopable) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        if(music.length() < 4 || !music.substring(music.length() - 4, music.length()).equals(".wav"))
            throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must be .wav)");
        else if(new File(music).length() > 1000000)
            throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must not be over 1 megabyte)");
        this.music = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + music;
        this.loopable = loopable;
        in = new FileInputStream(music);
        audioStreamMusic = new AudioStream(in);
        if(loopable) {
            audioData = audioStreamMusic.getData();
            loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioData);
        }
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(music));
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        long frames = stream.getFrameLength();
        length = (double) frames/format.getFrameRate();
    }

    /*
     * Also takes in whether the file size limit should be ignored
     */
    public Sound(String music, boolean loopable, boolean override) throws IOException {
        if(music.length() < 4 || !music.substring(music.length() - 4, music.length()).equals(".wav"))
            throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must be .wav)");
        if(!override) {
            if(new File(music).length() > 1000000)
                throw new IOException(music + " (Given file must not be over 1 megabyte)");
        }
        this.music = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + music;
        this.loopable = loopable;
        in = new FileInputStream(music);
        audioStreamMusic = new AudioStream(in);
        if(loopable) {
            audioData = audioStreamMusic.getData();
            loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioData);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Plays audio file
     */
    public void play() {
        if(loopable)
            AudioPlayer.player.start(loop);
        else {
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(music);
                audioStreamMusic = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStreamMusic);
            }
            catch(IOException error) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Stops audio file if playing
     */
    public void stop() {
        if(loopable)
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(loop);
        else
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(audioStreamMusic);
    }

    /*
     * Returns a string representation of the sound, including
     * the given name of the audio file as well as whether or
     * not it is loopable
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Sound[music = %s, loopable = %b]", music, loopable);
    }

    public boolean equals(Sound other) {
        if(music.equals(other.music))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Returns value of music
     */
    public String getMusic() {
        return music;
    }

    /*
     * Returns value of loopable
     */
    public boolean getLoopable() {
        return loopable;
    }

    /*
     * Returns value of length
     */
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /*
     * Plays group of Sounds
     */
    public static Thread playGroup(Sound[] sounds, boolean loopable) throws InterruptedException {
        return playGroup(new ArrayList<Sound>(Arrays.asList(sounds)), loopable);
    }

    /*
     * Plays group of Sounds
     */
    public static Thread playGroup(ArrayList<Sound> sounds, boolean loopable) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    int i = 0;
                    try {
                        sounds.get(0).play();
                        Thread.sleep((long) (sounds.get(0).getLength() * 1000));
                        for(i = 1; i < sounds.size(); ++i) {
                            sounds.get(i).play();
                            sounds.get(i - 1).stop();
                            Thread.sleep((long) (sounds.get(i).getLength() * 1000));
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        sounds.get(i).stop();
                        break;
                    }
                } while(loopable);
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public static void stopGroup(Thread t) {
        while(t != null && !t.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Test class I made to check if it was working:

```
package bob.classes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        Thread t = Sound.playGroup(new ArrayList<Sound>(Arrays.asList(new Sound("music.wav", false))), false);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Sound.stopGroup(t);
        Thread t2 = Sound.playGroup(new ArrayList<Sound>(Arrays.asList(new Sound("music2.wav", false))), false);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Sound.stopGroup(t2);
        //The program does not end right away here.
    }

}
```

It ran and stopped the audio, but it did not quit after that for some reason. Also, please let me know if there are any redundancies/unneeded for the thread stopping I am currently doing when posting answers. Thanks! :)

**Update 1:**

I have removed the isInterrupted flag as it does not change anything whether it is there or not. The code has been updated accordingly.

**Update 2:**

Here are some more details: When I stop the thread, an interruption exception happens. I expected the interruption of the thread in the test case of my Test class to stop the program immediately, but there is still a significant delay after the thread seems to have been interrupted. My belief is that the Thread.sleep() causes the program to finish only after the Thread.sleep() is finished. Nevertheless, I suppose the real problem is that the program has a significant delay after the sound stops.

Comment: Is the audio totally cut after stopGroup() execution ?

Comment: One note: ` public boolean equals(Sound other)` is **bad practice**. You should rather `@Overwrite public boolean equals(Object other)` . You are**overloading**, and that is a **dangerous** thing when talking about equals!

Comment: Seems to get interrupted just fine. Have you tried logging something in your exception handler? You also probably don't need the 'interrupted' flag since threads have their own.

Comment: @davidxxx Yup, it is.

Comment: You need to describe what you expect to happen and how it differs from what actually happens. You should also verify that you are or are not getting the interrupted exception. The code as posted appears to run and get interrupted as described in the documentation of the relevant APIS

Comment: @pvg I have tried printing at various other places, but it hasn't seemed to help. I am in fact getting the interrupted exception. I expected the interruption of the Thread to completely stop the thread, but I believe that the Thread.sleep() causes the program to only stop after it is done executing. Nevertheless, the program takes longer to stop than expected after interrupting it.

Comment: Can you update your question with this info, specifically, what precisely are you asking? Is it about program termination? Your question says 'thread won't interrupt'. The thread obviously interrupts. You even just said it interrupts. Please update your question (and title) with whatever it is you are specifically asking.

Comment: @pvg It has been updated.

Comment: Why not just call `System.exit` if you want the program to exit?

Comment: @pvg Actually, ending the program when wanting the program to exit is only a part of this test case. In a game I am making, I use playGroup() once to play a group of Sounds that make up the main theme. Then, if you lose all of your health, the group making up the main theme is to be stopped, and a new group of sounds for the ending music is played.

Comment: Ok so what's the problem? The music in this case stops. It's not even clear why you have this extra thread business to begin with since `AudioPlayer` actually _is_ a Thread (which is a crappy design but that's oldskool jdk classes for you).

Comment: I suppose that the music stops. Although, I was just wondering if there was a way to stop the extra delay that's happening at the end execution of playGroup(). As for having the thread, this is necessary in this case, so the infinite while loop actually stops when the JFrame (in my actual game) closes.

Comment: I don't think there is a delay where you think there is one and either way, you should debug and measure this and once again, describe your specific problem. We're on the third round of trying to figure out _what your actual question is_. Unless you can accurately describe that and preferably provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem, it's near-impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Well, the problem is the delay. I do not know how else to clarify. I wish to get rid of the delay. I added to my Test class to show an example where System.exit(0) would not quite work because you play another group of sounds after. So, the real problem is getting rid of this delay.

Comment: Where is the delay? Can you put some comments where you think it takes place? I just ran your new version, it starts a sound, stops a sound, immediately starts a new sound. There is no delay.

Comment: Done! And, by delay, I do not mean that it delays the task in main for the Test case. I mean that there is a delay specifically in the end of the program, which I do not understand why it's happening.

Comment: No, there is no delay. Put a print there and you'll see it runs instantly. The JVM takes a while to wind down but you can fix that with an exit if it really bothers you. _There is no delay anywhere in the execution of your program_. At all.

Comment: @pvg Oh.... So, that's it then. Thank you very much, and sorry for wasting your time! If you could put that as an answer, I will gladly accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142890/discussion-between-bob-jones-and-pvg).

Answer (score 0):

You request an interrupt to the thread here and you set the `isInterrupted` to `true` :

```
  public static void stopGroup(Thread t) {
        while(t != null && !t.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Test");
            t.interrupt();
            isInterrupted = true;
        }
    }
```

But in the `run()` method of the thread, your don't let to exit of the loop  :

```
do {
  ...
} while(loopable && isInterrupted);
```

You loop while `isInterrupted` is `true`. So, you never exit of the thread.
It should be rather :

```
while(loopable && !isInterrupted);
```

At last, you don't need to use a custom `isInterrupted` flag if you use the `Thread.interrupt()` method.
You can check it directly in this way in the loop :

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

Besides, I think that you have a limitation in your way of stopping the thread.
You don't test the interruption of the thread in the `play()` method.
So you are forced to let the play finish if it is started.
To avoid it, a sound play should also be a thread that could be interrupted.
You could so chain the `interrupt()` invocations.

Comment: Hello! I have removed the isInterrupted flag. I explained more about why I think what is happening is happening in the comments to my question. Also, I have now put the Sound.play() method in a thread. I do not understand what you mean, however, when you talk of chaining the interrupt invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Lets step back first: your first and *real* problem is: your code is 10 times more complicated than it ought to be. What I mean is: you have two condition variables (loopable and isInterrupted) for your while loop; but yet, you also rely on *interrupting* that thread in order to stop that loop.

My suggestion: you should step back and simplify your whole design. There should be **one** clear path that keeps that loop going. If you want to stop, do something like `loopable = false` in the correct place.

Meaning: you stop your thread by changing the variable that controls your while loop.

Then: get rid of this really nasty mix of static and non-static methods. That is just confusing the reader (including yourself). Finally, in order to debug this yourself: add simple print statements to understand which methods are entered, exited, ...

Comment: Hello! I have removed the isInterrupted flag. I explained more about why I think what is happening is happening in the comments to my question.

Comment: Err, maybe I am mistaken: but I do not see any `loopable = false` assignment in your code. So how is the loop supposed to stop when you never change the loop condition to false?

Comment: Well, it uses t.interrupt() to stop the Thread. The thread does, after a delay, interrupt. I have updated my question to help explain the situation better.

Comment: I do not use Thread.stop(), which is deprecated. I use Thread.interrupt();

Comment: Hmm. I am out of my wisdom by now. In that case: read that last paragraph of my answer. And try using that advise.